# C - Finding greatest, least, and mean with scanf problems

Tags: c, stdin, scanf

I've been struggling to find the solution to a few problems to what are, admittedly, basic assignments for a C programming course. The simplest of them I'll ask for help on here; the sheer length of time I've grappled with it is an indicator that I don't understand certain concepts.

The task has me read floating point values until EOF, separated by newlines; my program is to take those values and record the greatest and least values, and calculate a mean and print them with a specific format.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    float buffer[200];
    float least, greatest = 0, mean = 0;
    float total = 0, count = 0;
    int x=0, y = 0;
    while (buffer[x] != EOF)
      {
        y = scanf("%f\n", &buffer[x]);
        if (y == 1)     
        {
            if (isspace(buffer[x])==0)
            {
                if (x == 0) {least = buffer[x];}

                if(buffer[x]>greatest) {greatest = buffer[x];}

                if(buffer[x]<least) {least = buffer[x];}

                total += buffer[x];
                count++;
                x++;
            }
        }
      }
    mean = total/count;
    printf("%.2f ", least);
    printf("%.2f ", greatest);
    printf("%.2f\n", mean);

    return 0;
}
```

My code is able to handle well-formed inputs, but there's a twist: the marking scheme will test my program's reaction to having blank lines, which are to be ignored. My code works well only if every input follows the %f\n format specified, and prints an incorrect output if there are blank lines (or I could be entirely wrong and something is wrong fundamentally elsewhere).

I've experimented with a few solutions that have worked for other assignments, such as delimiters in the case of string inputs. This is the best I could come up with and it does work; again, it only fails if there are blank lines and I do not know what exactly goes wrong when there are blank lines.

Thanks for reading these walls of text! It's a first post for me and I'm not sure if I'm being rude, overly selfish, or not providing enough information about my case.

```
float* buffer;
float least, greatest = 0, mean = 0;
float total = 0, count = 0;
int x=0, y = 0;
buffer = (float*)malloc(200 * sizeof(float));
y = scanf("%f\n", &buffer[x]);
if (y == 0)
{
    return 1;
}
while (buffer[x] != EOF)
  {
    y = scanf("%f\n", buffer[x]);
    if (y == 0)
    {
        x++;
        continue;
    }
    if (isspace(buffer[x])==0)
    {
        if (x == 0) {least = buffer[x];}

        if(buffer[x]>greatest) {greatest = buffer[x];}

        if(buffer[x]<least) {least = buffer[x];}

        total += buffer[x];
        count++;

    }

    x++;
  }
mean = total/count;
printf("%.2f ", least);
printf("%.2f ", greatest);
printf("%.2f\n", mean);

return 0;
```

This is an alternative version of the body that I had worked on more with a probably more misguided use memory allocation to a buffer. However, this version segfaults for reasons I can only assume are with how I receive and store input; the problem remains close.

Comment: `while (buffer[x] != EOF)`. That looks wrong for starters. `buffer` is unitialised the first time you hit the while loop (and even for some of the subsequent iterations). Not sure what you are trying to do there.

Comment: You're right, this is the version of the code that I had come closest to succeeding; I think I had fixed that one but I've made sure to at least scanf something into the buffer so the loop will run.  I've made sure to move the x++ advancement out so if something goes wrong it won't infinitely loop on that while condition. Thanks for the extra eyes!

Comment: Please post a version that has all that in it. It's not good to talk about the currently posted version as it doesn't get past first base.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are approaching the problem in a way that makes it difficult to handle variations in your input file. While you can limit this to some extent by checking the `scanf` return, that isn't a total solution. Rather than read a discrete float with `scanf`, read an entire line with `fgets`. As you have described your input file, you have one float value per line (or nothing or garbage). That presents a perfect scenario for converting each line with `strtof`. Checking the return of `strtof` you either have a float on the line, or you don't, allowing you to easily handle blank or garbage lines.

Further, to compute the `least`, `greatest`, and `mean`, there is no reason to store every value for the duration of the program. Read each `value`, add the value to `total`, increment `count`, and test whether the current `value` is the new `least` or `greatest` and move on. No need to store it.

Here is a short example of reading floats from `stdin` and processing them into the values you desire:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define MAXL 200

int main()
{
    float value = 0.0;
    float least = (float)(INT_MAX);
    float greatest = (float)(-INT_MAX - 1);
    float mean = 0.0;
    float total = 0.0;
    size_t count = 0;
    char buffer[MAXL] = {0};

    while (fgets ( buffer, MAXL - 1, stdin) != NULL)
    {
        char *ep = buffer;
        value = strtof (buffer, &ep);
        if (errno == 0 && (ep != buffer && value != 0.0))
        {
            least = value < least ? value : least;
            greatest = value > greatest ? value : greatest;
            total += value;
            count++;
        }
    }

    mean = total/count;

    printf("%.2f ", least);
    printf("%.2f ", greatest);
    printf("%.2f\n", mean);

    return 0;
}
```

**Input**

```
$ cat dat/float.dat
100.3
dogfood

300.1
The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.


12.0

400.4
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/read_float_lines < dat/float.dat
12.00 400.40 203.20
```

Comment: I'd probably have never tried to use fgets as I'd been doubting my ability to use fgets for lines since it receives to char* and I thought I'd be opening a new can of worms trying to cast differently. Thank you very much for letting me know about strtof as well, it was exactly what I would have needed in this situtation but my brain's function repository isn't exactly full yet.

Comment: Glad to help, that's how we learn. In addition to `fgets` when reading a line, also consider `getline` (which allocates space for you and returns the actual number of characters read). 99% of the time, if you are reading values from multiple lines, reading the entire line and then parsing the input is the right way to go. Good luck.